# (My AccountMy WishlistMy CartCheckoutBlogLog) In-how to edit in magento

Tags: magento, header

(My AccountMy WishlistMy CartCheckoutBlogLog) In-how to edit in magento...i want to display all these links in my top navigation bar of magento instead of showing it in header section

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to remove links from the header.

For this search `<reference name="top.links">` in your layout folder.

For ex : My Account will be in customer.xml file as follows :

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_Customer -->
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment this code and search other in wishlist.xml, checkout.xml etc.

Next to add links in main navigation, there are various ways.

1 in page/html/topmenu.phtml you can add code to show the menus

2 Secondly you can do this as follows :

http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-adding-page-links-in-the-navigation-bar.html

Here is another useful link for more info

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/add_home_link_to_menu_bar